# Establish inequalities between sum of numbers in $(0,1)$

Tags: inequality

Consider six numbers in $(0,1)$  $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$. Suppose
$$
a<c+e\\
b<d\\
b<f
$$

Can we conclude that
$$
ab<cd+ef
$$

It seems to me yes since
$$
a<c+e \Leftrightarrow ab<cb+eb<cd+ef
$$

Do you agree?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Yes it is true since $b>0$, $c>0$ and $e>0$.

Comment: Your arument is correct if you replace $\Leftrightarrow$ with $\Rightarrow$ (which is all you need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z>0$ then for any real numbers $x,y$ we have,

$$x < y \iff zx<zy$$

---

Here,

$$a<c+e$$

Thus as $b>0$,

$$ab<(c+e)b = cb+eb \quad (0)$$

Moreover because $b<d$ and $c>0$ we have,

$$cb<cd \quad (1)$$

Likewise, as $b<f$ and $e>0$,

$$eb<ef \quad (2)$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get,

$$cb+eb<cd+ef$$

Therefore combining it with $(0)$ we can deduce,

$$\boxed{ ab<cb+eb<cd+ef}$$